# Complex structure of Term-Document Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, term-document-matrix

I am quite new to R, sorry if my question will trivial. I try to work with clouds of words. The function comparison.cloud is supposed to accept a Term-Document Matrix with words' frequencies matrix built like that:

```
head(term.matrix,1)
      Docs
Terms SOTU 2010 SOTU 2011
  ’ll         3         8

colnames(term.matrix)
[1] "SOTU 2010" "SOTU 2011"
```

I try to build such a matrix myself but I am confused why "Terms" is not considered as a column name and why "Docs" is above the two column names "SOTU 2010" and "SOTU 2011"...

Can someone explain me that please?

Answer (score 0):

The `dimnames` attribute of a matrix, if not `NULL`, is a list of the form `list(rownames, colnames)` storing the row names and column names of the matrix.

```r
x <- matrix(1:9, 3L, 3L)
x
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    4    7
## [2,]    2    5    8
## [3,]    3    6    9

dimnames(x) <- list(letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:3])
x
##   A B C
## a 1 4 7
## b 2 5 8
## c 3 6 9
```

Sometimes, it is convenient for the list itself to have names. These names act somewhat like axis titles:

```r
names(dimnames(x)) <- c("lo", "UP")
x
##    UP
## lo  A B C
##   a 1 4 7
##   b 2 5 8
##   c 3 6 9
```

`lo` is printed on the same line as the column names, but it is really the title of the first dimension. Similarly, `UP` is the title of the second dimension.

`TermDocumentMatrix` and `DocumentTermMatrix` objects are not true R matrices. They store nonzero elements in triplet format for efficiency, as well as some metadata. However, like true R matrices, they can have a `dimnames` attribute. Since the rows and columns represent terms and documents (or vice versa), package `tm` assigns names `Terms` and `Docs` to the `dimnames`.

Taking an example from `vignette("tm")`:

```r
library("tm")
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
reuters <- VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578, mode = "binary"), 
                   readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(reuters)
str(tdm)
## List of 6
##  $ i       : int [1:2255] 14 35 49 157 202 203 233 274 290 291 ...
##  $ j       : int [1:2255] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ v       : num [1:2255] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ nrow    : int 1266
##  $ ncol    : int 20
##  $ dimnames:List of 2
##   ..$ Terms: chr [1:1266] "..." "\"(it)" "\"demand" "\"expansion" ...
##   ..$ Docs : chr [1:20] "127" "144" "191" "194" ...
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "TermDocumentMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
##  - attr(*, "weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
```

Hence:

```r
y <- as.matrix(tdm)[1:6, 1:6]
y
##             Docs
## Terms        127 144 191 194 211 236
##   ...          0   0   0   0   0   0
##   "(it)        0   0   0   0   0   0
##   "demand      0   1   0   0   0   0
##   "expansion   0   0   0   0   0   0
##   "for         0   0   0   0   0   0
##   "growth      0   0   0   0   0   0

dimnames(y)
## $Terms
## [1] "..."         "\"(it)"      "\"demand"    "\"expansion" "\"for"       "\"growth"   
## 
## $Docs
## [1] "127" "144" "191" "194" "211" "236"
```